# Use HDMI-out on Windows to drive old 30" (Dual-link DVI) Apple monitor

Tags: hdmi, cinema-display, pc, dvi

I have an AMD Ryzen (TUF Gaming) Windows 10 laptop with a Geforce card and HDMI output. Try what I may, it fails to drive a decade-old 30" dual-link DVI Apple monitor.

My current setup uses two powered convertors:

1. HDMI -> DisplayPort (powered convertor; Comsol brand)
2. DisplayPort -> Mini DisplayPort (unpowered adapter; generic)
3. Mini DisplayPort to Dual-link DVI (powered convertor; Apple brand)

However, Windows can't even identify a monitor is connected. The Cinema Display has a black screen with power light on.

In the past, I successfully used links #2 and 3 of this chain with a DisplayPort-enabled laptop. But the new HDMI -> DP convertor (link #1) seems to break the chain.

Any ideas? Even if only to get it working at low resolution?

--
Other things I tried:

1. Generic USB-C to Mini DisplayPort convertor didn't work. (The laptop has a non-Thunderbolt USB-C 3.1 port)
2. Mini DisplayPort to DVI adapter (unpowered) as link #3 didn't work either.

Comment: Have a look at https://superuser.com/questions/332099/does-a-hdmi-to-dvi-dual-link-adapter-exist-i-dont-care-about-the-price

Comment: @Tetsujin - thanks, that's a good lead. I had  used the HDMI-to-DP and DP-to-DVI convertors that the other guy also used , but not his HDMI audio de-embedder device. My problem was, unlike him,  I got no video at all, not even low-res, in the Cinema display (but this may be a separate known problem with the display's signal processor). I gave up and returned the HDMI-to-DP convertor I had bought.